# Scoped time sink implementation

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written a little class that is intended to be used to spend unused time in a loop body, sleeping.

That is, I have a loop. I want every iteration to take at least X seconds. If the operations actually complete quicker, the excess time shall be spent sleeping.

My implementation is based on a class that is created in a scope, and whose destructor sleeps for the required amount of time when the object's lifetime ends.

Is this a sane approach to the problem? Are there any flaws in the implementation? Is there potential for improvements regarding coding style?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class TimeSink {
public:
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds duration_ms;

    TimeSink(duration_ms const & min_duration)
    : min_duration(min_duration), start(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) {}

    ~TimeSink() {
        time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto elapsed = end-start;
        auto remaining_time_to_sleep = min_duration - elapsed;
        if (remaining_time_to_sleep > epsilon) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(remaining_time_to_sleep);
        }
    }

private:
    typedef std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> time_point;
    const duration_ms epsilon = duration_ms(0);
    duration_ms min_duration;
    time_point start;
};

int main() {
    TimeSink t(TimeSink::duration_ms(1000));
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Allow users to customize your TimeSink class**

We achieve this by making it a template class:

```
template <typename TimeUnit, typename Clock>
class time_sink;
```

This will allow your class to be used in different scenarios; it removes restrictions.

Since the `TimeUnit` template parameter is the one most likely to be changed, we can provide a default argument for `Clock`:

```
template <typename TimeUnit, typename Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock>
class time_sink;
```

**Your destructor can be simplified**

Instead of doing...

```
time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto elapsed = end-start;
auto remaining_time_to_sleep = min_duration - elapsed;
if (remaining_time_to_sleep > epsilon)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(remaining_time_to_sleep);
}
```

...we can do:

```
auto time_spent = Clock::now() - begin;
if ( time_spent < min_duration )
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( min_duration - time_spent );
}
```

I find this clearer and easier to understand.

**Consider using `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` as your default clock type**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263277/difference-between-stdsystem-clock-and-stdsteady-clock) stack overflow question should tell you why that's the preferred clock type for timing function execution.

```
template <typename TimeUnit, typename Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
class time_sink;
```

**Concise usage with the `std::chrono_literals` namespace and a template function**

This would simply make the code shorter. Note that there is a repetition, as we must define `time_sink`'s time unit type.

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using time_sink = time_sink<std::chrono::milliseconds>;
time_sink{ 500ms };
```

In order to make usage fully concise (avoid repetition), we can use a template function and implement the idea proposed by [5gon12eder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/67456/5gon12eder), in [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114189/scoped-time-sink-implementation#comment211632_114200) comment which simply creates the `time_sink` object and uses template function type deduction to fill in the details.

```
template <typename TimeUnit, typename Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
time_sink<TimeUnit, Clock> make_time_sink( TimeUnit const minimum_duration )
{
    return time_sink<TimeUnit, Clock>{ minimum_duration };
}
```

This allows us to create a `time_sink` in a short and clear way:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
make_time_sink( 500ms );
// rest of function code, etc.
```

**The improved code**

Here's what the final code could look like:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

template <typename TimeUnit, typename Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
class time_sink
{
public:
    time_sink( TimeUnit const minimum_duration ) :
        min_duration{ minimum_duration },
        begin{ Clock::now() }
    {}

    ~time_sink()
    {
        auto time_spent = Clock::now() - begin;
        if ( time_spent < min_duration )
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for( min_duration - time_spent );
        }
    }

private:
    TimeUnit min_duration;
    std::chrono::time_point<Clock> begin;
};

template <typename TimeUnit, typename Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
time_sink<TimeUnit, Clock> make_time_sink( TimeUnit const minimum_duration )
{
    return time_sink<TimeUnit, Clock>{ minimum_duration };
}
```

**Sample usage**

As [5gon12eder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/67456/5gon12eder) points out, you must also ensure that you keep the return of `make_time_sink` in order to prevent `time_sink`'s destructor from running early, since destructors are called at the "end of the full expression, for nameless temporaries" ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)).

```
void f()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    // we keep the return of make_time_sink in order to prevent
    // time_sink's destructor from executing before the end of the function
    auto ts = make_time_sink( 500ms );
    // ... do work ...
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

Comment: Is it intentional that the “obvious choice” for the clock type is once `std::chrono::steady_clock` and once `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`? As for the function, is it meant to be a convenience wrapper around the constructor (then why the lambda?) or would it block for up tp the specified amount of time after calling the lambda (then why the name?)?

Comment: 1. I changed it without really thinking about it, I'll add a note about it. Thanks for pointing this out. 2. I did leave this part kind of vague. I didn't see it as a wrapper, but now that you point it out, that's even better. Great suggestion.

Comment: I like the updated answer except for one important detail: You should assign the result of `make_time_sink` to  a variable, otherwise the destructor will block right away when the temporary is destroyed. It doesn't matter for the `main`, however,  because there is no other statement in its body anyway, but you should change it in the shorter snippet above.

Comment: @5gon12eder Thanks for pointing out the oversight. I'll include a better example.

Comment: You seem to use the braced initializer list everywhere. Is this the new way to initialize things? When would we resort to the "old" style?

Comment: @moooeeeep It is a newer way to initialize things. You can use which ever way you want as long as you keep certain things in mind. Brace initialization prevents narrowing conversions (`int i{ 3.2 }` is illegal), however, you should be aware that this same syntax is used for initializer-list constructors: if we do `std::vector<int> v{ 3 }`, that's a vector with one element, but `std::vector<int> v( 3 )` is a vector of 3 default-initialized elements. The parentheses initialization can have other issues; look up the most vexing parse.